# recognizing facial expressions using Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect, face-recognition

I am trying to do some work using Kinect and the Kinect SDK.

I was wondering whether it is possible to detect facial expressions (e.g. wink, smile etc) using the Kinect SDK Or, getting raw data that can help in recognizing these.

Can anyone kindly suggest any links for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am also working on this and i considered 2 options:

1. Face.com API:

   there is a [C# client library](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/08/using-face-api-in-c/) and there are a lot of examples in their documentation
2. EmguCV

   [This guy](http://www.geek-press.com/?p=23) Talks about the basic face detection using EmguCV and Kinect SDK and you can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real-ti) to recognize faces

Presently i stopped developing this but if you complete this please post a link to your code.

Comment: Face.com is no longer available since it was acquired by Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not featured within the Kinect for Windows SDK due to the limitations of Kinect in producing high-resolution images. That being said, libraries such as OpenCV and AForge.NET have been sucessfuly used to detected finger and facial recognition from both the raw images that are returned from Kinect, and also RGB video streams from web cams. I would use this computer vision libraries are a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, MS is releasing the "Kinect for PC" along with a [new SDK version in february](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/). This has a new "Near Mode" which will offer better resolution for close-up images. Face and finger recognition might be possible with this. You can read a MS press release here, for example:
[T3.com](http://www.t3.com/news/microsoft-kinect-for-pc-coming-early-2012)

Answer (score 2):

The new Kinect SDK1.5 is released and contains the facial detection and recognition

you can download the latest SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx)

and check this website for more details about kinect [face tracking](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/194-kinect/4253-kinect-sdk-15-now-with-face-tracking.html)

Comment: There is no facial recognition in the Kinect SDK 1.5. The second article you cited specifically says "Notice that this isn't face recognition, as some sources are reporting."